# Failing to include C++ REST casablanca

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, casablanca

I need your help as I've followed the exact instructions in this link (https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http%20Client%20Tutorial ).
I've downloaded a new version of visual studio 2012 and installed the Nuget package for my Solution yet whenever I try to include

```
<cpp/http_client.h>
```

I keep getting error of "Cannot open source file".

Comment: Can you verify that the nuget package was installed properly. Check to see if there is a "packages" folder in the root of your project and that the casablanca files are all there.

Comment: Yes, here is a screen shot of the environment

Comment: It is `#include <cpprest\http_client.h>` when you use the Nuget package.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xckyuj40qc8qqbb/AAB1o2OKKq8wUBWH--II3nvYa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Search casablanca -> install cpprestsdk.

Once you need it to be redownloaded: Rigt click on your solution -> Restore NuGetPackages.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks but this works only on visual studio 2012+, I got it working now.
When i posed the question it was for visual studio 2010